# sort full name in alphabetical order in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a list of members names and I want to sort them in alphabetical order. I have the members names as full names like Joe Bloggs, is there a way I can order them alphabetically by their last name.

I know its "select * from member ORDER BY name ASC";

Comment: `ORDER BY name,lastname`

Comment: I don't have a last name the members name is just name.The members name is their first and last name together. I don't have firstname and lastname its just name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a *nice* way to do it. This is why people typically store the last name in its own column.

You would have to create an algorithm to determine how to split the full name into constituent parts (i.e. perhaps you could split by space and take the last value, which would handle `John Smith` and `John James Smith` and `John Smith-Fontleroy`). i.e.

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) AS last_name
```

This is all quite inefficient, though, compared to sorting a column called `lastName`.

Comment: @amdixon sure - example added to back up my middle paragraph. The last sentence is the main point though.